# Differences in referencing forms in VBA Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

**Intro:**

I have two separate forms.

1. frmABC
2. frmXYZ

I have **frmABC** in focus and I run a procedure that will "Tick" a checkbox called **ChkConfirmed** on **frmXYZ**.

---

**Question:**

What is the **difference** between these two ways of referencing another form?

**1**. Form_frmXYZ.ChkConfirmed = True

**2**. Forms!frmXYZ.ChkConfirmed = True

---

For some reason, only **#2** works in this scenario. For me this is bewildering purely beacuse I have always used **#1** and it has never complained before (when I say complain, I mean it does the job).

But, when I use **#1** here and step through the code, it definitely runs the code but does not check any boxes...just nothing.

So, I would love to know the technical differences to help me understand when to use each one and in what cases.

---

EDIT:
Actual code snippet (as requested)

**#1 Version**

[image]

**#2 Version**

[image]

Comment: I 100% cannot duplicate this, I have Form1 which has a button that is used to change the value of a checkbox on Form2 and both methods work.   Do you have any other OnUpdate or BeforeUpdate code that could be interfering here?

Comment: I've added the code snippet so you can see @Newd. When I step through the code it doesn't run anything else afterwards that I can see...unless access runs ninja code behind the scenes =P

Comment: So just to clarify, it does run through the `Forms!frmAAdmin9110YearEnd!ChkValidated = True`? And can you comment out the other lines of code and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: In your question you said the name of the checkbox was `ChkConfirmed ` but your VBA says `ChkValidated`...

Comment: @Invent-Animate - Just an example - I wasn't going to put snippets in originally

Comment: @Newd Yes it works for #2 and if I change it to #1 nothing happens.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue. I've reproduced everything that we know and I was able to mark the checkbox as true on another form immediately after closing the current form.

Comment: I always follow the rule that if you are trying to change something in/on a form using VBA written outside of that form (i.e. in separate module or something) then you have to use `Forms!myForm`... in order to go through the objects and allow access to find the form you want to reference... as per the "not on these forms" quadrant on this cheat sheet: http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access (I think >=97) treats **Forms** as a **Class** which means your forms are now a class module and can have all [class behaviors] including instancing.

`Form_your_formname`: you are referencing the Form via the Class module.

`Forms!your_form name`: You are referencing the form by its form name.

To access a form via `Forms!form_name`, the form must already have been loaded. Otherwise the form won't be reachable and you will get an error message ***`"the referenced ...... not found"`***

On the other hand, `Form_form_name` can be accessed at any time as a class. It can have multiple instances like all classes do. Accessing an **unopened form** via its class module will cause the form is being instanced. This means Access will create a new hidden instance of that Form.

To test this try following.

1. Create a new form called: frm_test with a text box in it called: txt_id
2. go to your immediate window and try following code:
3. **Edit** forgot to mention. The test form hast to have a vba module attached to it then only it becomes a class module

`Form_frm_test.txt_id = 1
 Form_frm_test.visible = true
?Form_frm_test.hwnd
 docmd.openform "frm_test"
?Forms!frm_test.hwnd`

Now you will see two instance of the frm_test form and each of them will have their own window handle.

**to answer your question:**

1. But, when I use #1 here and step through the code, it definitely runs the code but does not check any boxes...just nothing.

   its because your form is being instanced and its hidden.
2. So, I would love to know the technical differences to help me understand when to use each one and in what cases.

   Technical explanation given above.
   if your form is already loaded you can use the Form!form_name / form_name to access it. If you are instancing use the class name.

Comment: Access can treat forms only as a classes if they have a (class) module. See the HasModule-Property of the form.

Comment: @PhilS Sorry, I was mistaken. Not sure what I was thinking.

Comment: @Invent-Animate phil is correct you need to have a "class module" attached to it to get the class behaviors

Comment: Very Neat, so basically that would mean that if it is being instanced then as soon as the function ends it would clear from memory?

Comment: no you can keep the instances active by saving the hwnd in a public variable.

Comment: I meant mainly in this situation, so it would open a hidden instance of the form then wipe it from memory almost instantly.

Comment: no the instance will remain loaded until you close it, or the original/Main form is closed. If the main form is closed all instance will also be closed.

Comment: @krish 
>its because your form is being instanced and its hidden. 
- by hidden do you mean it is not in focus?
I'm not completely versed with the hwnd side of coding - do you have useful sources that might help me further understand this and instances?

Comment: @krish so does that mean he should be able to put in `Forms!frmAAdmin9110YearEnd.Visible = True` and it will pop up?

Answer (score -2):

To be honest, I've never seen your 1st example used, ever... In fact a quick test in Access 2010 fails with an "Object Required" error message. All the code I've ever done uses the exclamation, which (someone correct me if I'm worng) works in all circumstances where you would need to reference another form for something.

Comment: Maybe you should try again - it definitely works... just not sure why it doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: One thing I have learned about access is that there is too many ways to reference objects.  But Cocojay is correct, these do work.

Comment: What version of Access are we talking about here?

Comment: Take a look in the tags ;-)

Comment: @Gene - to be honest I've been using #1 method since Access 2000 so it can't be a version issue.

Comment: @cocojay - Please don't  misunderstanding, i'm not saying your wrong, just I've never seen it andit failed in testing.  I've put the file on i used to test on dropbox, maybe you can look at it and see what I saw. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ok66933kz0rzwns/Test%28checkbox%291.accdb?dl=0

Comment: The first version of the code-syntax will most likely fail if the Form referenced by the code has the HasModule-Property set to "No". Then there is no class module that can be instanced and no object afterwards, hence the error.

Comment: @Gene - Hey Gene, I had a look at your code. Just a couple things to make sure you can replicate the issue I had. Design formXYZ and on the ribbon click on "View in Code" this will create a class object for the form in the code. 
Then, when running make sure both forms are open. Give that a go and let me know if it works.